# OPENSSL and private key

Tags: c, security, openssl, rsa

Openssl is a great security library and I use it from time to time. 
When I generate RSA keys I have RSA object with private and public key data. OK. Fine. I'm happy with that. I can print private key to the printer. And here come's the question.

Is it possible to create a valid RSA object only from the entered private key (RSA->n)?
I made key check and it asks for a valid p and q. OK. I entered p and q. But encrypting is not working properly...any ideas?

TIA!

Comment: Your question is not clear; are you asking whether it's possible to generate the public key from the private key?

Comment: You need at least one more piece of information, either the public or private exponent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure you entered p and q primes?

Comment: In a new RSA structure I entered d, e,p and q values (other data is empty). RSA_check_key accepts RSA structure. But encryption does not work! Maybe it is bad to work with RSA structure directly, but is there any other way?

Comment: The question is it possible from private key (in hex)

Comment: "3F710BD31FE80932CE732A181609230C20165D1CDFB3FC4A76B72693F6A56D2A9508BCD16F9DCFE61DA1B4C1F3559F3C19B50E115980C501D8C672B1F4248941" to make a valid private key.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out. RSA object must have 5 valid variables: n, p, q, d and e. Thanks!